# copy of system dll doesn't work

Tags: c, winapi, dll

I have windows 8.1. I copied User32.dll from C:\Windows\System32 in E:\ folder. So first of all, that i have mentioned, if you make just copy-paste, the content of original User32.dll and copy of User32.dll is not the same!!! I find out it, using WinMerge program. So, I have writen my program on C, like this:

```
void copy(FILE* input_dll)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("E:\\user32.dll", "wb");
    int size_of_base_input_dll_file;
   // Get the Size of base_file 
    fseek(input_dll, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_of_base_input_dll_file = ftell(input_dll);
    //move on a begin of dll
    fseek(input_dll, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_base_input_dll_file; ++i)
    {
        char symbol = fgetc(input_dll);
        fputc(symbol, f);
    }
}

int main()
 {
       FILE* user32 = fopen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\user32.dll","rb");
       copy(user32);
 }
```

Now WinMerge shows that the content of C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll and E:\user32.dll is the same, but file C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll is bigger than E:\user32.dll on 100 KB!!! How does it can be?

When I try to load copy of user32.dll(E:\user32.dll) with WinApi LoadLibraryA function, it returns NULL, no matter if copy of user32.dll (E:\user32.dll) was got with using my function copy or with copy-paste.

So my questions:

1. why the content of dll the same, but the size of dll is different?
2. why the content of dll the same, but i can't load E:\user32.dll with LoadLibraryA and can load C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll with LoadLibraryA ?
3. and why copy-paste make wrong copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running a 32 bit process under the WOW64 emulator. That means you are subject to file system redirection. The system redirects `system32` to `syswow64`.

That means you are not copying the file you are expecting to copy. When you copy in Explorer, you are copying from the 64 bit system folder (system32), and so copy a 64 bit DLL. When you copy in your 32 bit program, you are copying from the 32 bit system folder (syswow64), and so copy a 32 bit DLL.

When you copy in Explorer, the copied file is therefore a 64 bit DLL and so cannot be loaded into your process. When you copy in your 32 bit program, the copied file is a 32 bit DLL and so can be loaded into your process.

Your WinMerge is a 32 bit program, so it too is redirected to the 32 bit system directory, `syswow64`.

You can reach the 64 bit system32 directory using one of the following approaches:

1. Switch to a 64 bit process.
2. Use the `sysnative` alias to access the 64 bit system directory from inside WOW64.
3. Disable file system redirection.

The final option is absolutely to be discouraged because it can have many unexpected consequences.

Whatever you are really trying to do, copying system directories into other folders is surely not the solution to your problem.

More details here: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

Comment: Windows is crazy. This is one of the most ridiculous things I've ever seen.

Comment: @FUZxxl Not really. It's a consequence of MS trying to maintain lots of binary compatibility. Had they not done this they would have broken a lot of programs.

Comment: @Fuzxxl: How would you have solved the problem? You do understand the problem, that needed to be solved, right?

Comment: @IInspectable they could have placed the 64 bit dlls in a new directory (e.g. `system64` or something like that) leaving `system32` for 32 bit binaries. They could have also made provisions for this kind of problem in the first place. Unix systems manage just fine to support multiple ISAs without any of these ridiculous problems.

Comment: @FUZxxl Programs on UNIX systems are typically delivered in source format and so re-compiled. MS were trying to ensure that existing 32 bit executable would run unchanged. They achieved that.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Why would a proposed `system64` directory be a solution? And what problem would it solve?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can still run Solaris binaries from the 90s on modern Solaris. Commercial UNIX systems of course provided facilities to allow programs to be distributed as binaries. Do you really think that no software is being sold in binary form for UNIX systems?

Comment: @IInspectable The problem is that you need a different directory for 32 bit system DLL files and 64 bit system DLL files. Windows solves this with a crude redirection hack, it could have been solved by simply giving a new name to the directory with the 64 bit DLLs-

Comment: @FUZxxl Perhaps MS wanted to make life easy for devs that had hard coded system32 and could not be bother to change that when they moved to 64 bit. All the same, it's not exactly a problem. As soon as you understand the design, it's easy and transparent.

Comment: @FUZxxl: You are making up a problem that isn't, and propose a solution that isn't. Your proposed solution makes porting software more difficult than it needs to be. Your proposed solution likewise has zero benefit. It is a non-solver to a non-issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think that giving 32 bit and 64 bit processes a different view on the file system for selected system directories is “easy and transparent.” It's a crude hack that can possibly cause a lot of headache. I imagine e.g. backup programs written without this in mind possibly not backing up the `system32` directory correctly.

Comment: @IInspectable If it's a non-issue, why did Microsoft need to introduce this crude redirection hack? Apparently it is an issue.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The **solution** Microsoft implemented is a non-issue, no matter how much you would like to believe otherwise. Calling something "wrong" requires, that you address what actually is wrong. Or be thought a fool. Have a nice day.

Comment: @IInspectable I did address what is actually wrong with that, see my penultimate comment. Maybe it's my UNIX perspective, but I don't believe that randomly redirecting parts of the file system depending on ISA is a sustainable way to fix design issues in the way your multi ISA support works.

Comment: @FUZxxl That would be a badly written backup program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Or maybe just a backup program written before 64 bit Windows was introduced? How is a program that doesn't anticipate future technical decisions it cannot anticipate badly written? And how is introducing even more corner cases into an operating system good design? This could have been solved without introducing any new complexity or intransparency, but apparently that's not the Windows™ way of thinking.

Comment: @FUZxxl I suspect that MS knows what they are doing and came up with the best solution to the problem, given all the constraints. But hey, maybe I'm just being charitable! Anyway it is what it is, and we just have to get on with it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sometimes I think that Microsoft is a company full of comically evil genuises who think of novel ways to make an operating system as complicated as possible but then I just remember Hanlon's razor. In German we have a saying, “the opposite of good is good intentions,” it applies to this situation quite well I think.